# sendMessage causes "Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property Symbol.toPrimitive on cross-origin object"

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, cross-domain

I'm a developer who wants to load my web app inside an iframe in a Cordova app.

I have followed all the steps in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage.

My iframe:

```
    <iframe src="https://www.myweb.com" id="appFrame" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"> Your browser doesn't support iframes </iframe>
```

In the cordova main html js (index.js):

```
window.onload = function() {
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    alert("app - " + data);

}, false);

var frame = document.getElementById('appFrame').contentWindow;
setInterval(function() { console.log("frame " + frame); frame.postMessage('action', '*'); }, 1000);
```

In my web application:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        alert("event message " + event.data);
        if (event.data == 'action') {
            (event.source as Window).postMessage(command, event.origin);
            window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                callback(event.data);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return true;
            }, false);}
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return true;
    }, false);
}
```

I run the app in Cordova with the "browser" platform, which creates a local server with the following settings:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*://*.myweb.com/*" />
```

And I my web application, in Laravel I have enabled the following headers:

```
->header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin") // unsafe-none same-origin same-origin-allow-popups
 ->header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp") // unsafe-none require-corp
 ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
 ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization");
```

But I always get when executing "frame.postMessage('action', '*');", I always get the error "Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property Symbol.toPrimitive on cross-origin object".

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You send non CORS headers back from the server with

```
 header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin")
```

Cordova apps have no domain/origin. You need to setup a CORS back end.